# Python. How can I output each instance of a for loop as a nested list, lists inside a list

Tags: python

I have a code that checks if the number in the range is even or odd and performs an operation on them respectively. It appends the results of the operation into a list. However, I am trying to append each instance of the for loop as a separate list within a list. How can I modify my code to do this?

```
series = []
for i in range(13, -0, -1):
    while i > 1:
        if i % 2 == 0:
            i = i//2
            series.append(i)
        else:
            i = i*3+1
            series.append(i)
print(series)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the inner list just after the `for` to get a fresh one at each iterate, then save it in `series`

```
series = []
for i in range(13, -0, -1):
    inner = []
    while i > 1:
        if i % 2 == 0:
            i = i // 2
            inner.append(i)
        else:
            i = i * 3 + 1
            inner.append(i)
    series.append(inner)

[[40, 20, ...], [6, 3,...], ...]
```

You might want to keep the correspondance with the value that led to this list, using a dict like

```
series = {}
for i in range(13, -0, -1):
    keep_i = i
    inner = []
    while i > 1:
        if i % 2 == 0:
            i = i // 2
            inner.append(i)
        else:
            i = i * 3 + 1
            inner.append(i)
    series[keep_i] = list(inner)

{13: [40, 20,...], 12: [6, 3,...],...}
```

Comment: The result would be inner list in series list/dictionary. There will be only one item "inner list" in "series list/dictionary" since whatever the condition maybe "i" is appended to "inner list". maybe there should be two lists. Not sure.

Comment: @AchuthVarghese From the reading "each instance of the for loop as a separate list" so each run should go in a separate list, that's doesn't talk about the if/else, just each run of the for is in a list

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add the `[]` over each i like so: `series.append([i])`:

```
series = []
for i in range(13, -0, -1):
    while i > 1:
        if i % 2 == 0:
            i = i//2
            series.append([i])
        else:
            i = i*3+1
            series.append([i])
print(series)
```

Comment: Thank you, but your example is for while loop,  i need it for "for" loop. Azro got it right. Please keep contributing and welcome!